# Storage engine size and how many rows and columns

Tags: mysql

What will happen if the size of the storage engine is fully occuiped .
What is the maximum no of rows and column the storage engine takes.

Comment: See [Limits in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/8.0/en/limits.html)

Comment: But it does not have information about all storage engines